# View like function in Julia Juno

Tags: dataframe, julia, juno-ide

id like to start using *Julia* for computing instead of *Python*. But so far I miss very important tool - View-like function. There is `View()` function in *R* that displays whole dataframe. This is very handfull tool, I cant even imagime use Julia withouth this. Is just too early to use Julia?

So far I tried `print(df)`.
I use Juno in the Atom IDE.

Print screen from R looks like this, I want to open my dataframe in another window, not i console.

[image]

Comment: how about `@show df` or `showall(df)`?

Comment: perhaps `display` ?
Your gonna have to give use more info like a screenshot from R.

Comment: This is being implemented. I can't find the issue but I know it's on the list.

Comment: added https://github.com/queryverse/ElectronDisplay.jl as part of my answer

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what you need because I've not used R, but maybe you're looking for the printtable() method.

```
printtable(df::AbstractDataFrame; header::Bool = true,  
    separator::Char = ',',
    quotemark::Char = '"',
    nastring::AbstractString = "NA")
```

please note, oddly, that it only accepts named arguments

hope this helps fam

Answer (score 3):

[Not available so far](https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/issues/153).

Although, as commented in the issue discussion, this is available for Jupyter notebooks (by calling `stringmime("text/html", mydataframe)` underneath). 
What's currently missing is for Atom to pick up the generated table html. A quick search didn't throw any info on whether Atom can/is displaying tables.

EDIT:

Another alternative is using [ElectronDisplay.jl](https://github.com/queryverse/ElectronDisplay.jl), which does a pretty-display, although outside the Juno (or Atom) ecosystem:

```
using ElectronDisplay
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])
electrondisplay(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Julia 1.3: [TableView](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/TableView.jl): it allows browsing, sorting and filtering.
In Juno it display the table/DataFrame on the Plot Panel:

[image: screenshot]